# django-registration и ImageField

Tags: django

Если кратко: без поля avatar в Profile все работает отлично, но с этим полем django-registration работает некорректно. В шаблоне выводит выбор файла для avatar, тем не менее когда тыркаю "зарегестрироваться" регистратор ругается на аватар, который не выбран (хотя я его выбираю). В админке джанги все работает хорошо, аватарки выбираются и сохряняются.

```
models.py


from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, city, MyUsername, phone, first_name, last_name, address, gender, birth_date, info, avatar, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            city=city,
            MyUsername=MyUsername,
            phone=phone,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            address=address,
            gender=gender,
            birth_date=birth_date,
            info=info,
            avatar=avatar
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, city, MyUsername, phone, first_name, last_name, address, gender, birth_date, info, avatar, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            city=city,
            MyUsername=MyUsername,
            phone=phone,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            address=address,
            gender=gender,
            birth_date=birth_date,
            info=info,
            avatar=avatar
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    MyUsername = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    gender = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    info = models.TextField(null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True)

    object = ProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'MyUsername'
   ]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        return True

   def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.is_admin
```

Формы
    forms.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from user_registration.models import Profile


class MyCustomUserForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            Profile.USERNAME_FIELD,
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'city',
            'MyUsername',
            'phone',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'address',
            'gender',
            'birth_date',
            'info',
            'avatar',
        ]
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Регистрация</h1>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<dl class="register">
{% for field in form %}
    <dt>{{ field.label_tag }}</dt>
    <dd class="clearfix">{{ field }}
    {% if field.help_text %}<div class="clearfix">{{ field.help_text }}</div>{% endif %}
    {% if field.errors %}<div class="myerrors clearfix">{{ field.errors }}</div>{% endif %}
    </dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
<input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" / class="clearfix">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: в какой части не выводит не очень понял, если в шаблоне то нужно ставить проверку есть ли изображение, если есть показывать url.

Comment: Ну, формы все подставляются, в том числе и форма для загрузки изображения. Я заливаю туда картинку, а она отказывается загружаться.
P.S. приложу код шаблона

Comment: укажите еще ошибку, какая выдается

Comment: Это последняя версия джанги. Расширение пользователя именно такое, какое представлина в доках последней джанги.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

без enctype="multipart/form-data" загрузка файлов не работает.